# How to use the refresh parameter in CodeIgniter redirect function

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

Could sombody please tell me why do we need to use a "refresh" parameter for redirect function in codeigniter.

```
redirect('/index.php/it_inventory/get_users', 'refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with core PHP 
header("Location:url_here") so this might be a new addition in your knowledge that redirection using header with the following syntax is also possible which is used in CI.
When you pass the second argument refresh so the follow line works. And its optional.
header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri)

Answer (score 1):

It's already set by default to "location"

The second parameter is the redirect method. By default it is set to Location, but can also be changed to refresh. This is useful for Windows servers as they might give you some fuss regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use 'refresh' or 'location' method then by default set 'location' method. 'location' method sometime create problem in windows server.So you need set 'refresh' method. For more details you can see codeigniter user guide then "redirect()" function. Here's the link : [URL Helper User Guide of Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).
Here describe about redirect() url helper function.